# Inheritance in CSS? Possible to do this without copy and paste?

Tags: css, inheritance, jquery-ui

I'm trying to follow the nifty tutorial at http://www.kriesi.at/archives/create-a-multilevel-dropdown-menu-with-css-and-improve-it-via-jquery and well, it hit me that I'm trying to use jquery's CSS for theming.. So if I have a menu like

```
<ul id="AVPNav">
  <li><a href="#">Agfdts</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="~/Apfgsdfg.aspx?node=add">Add</a></li>
      <li><a href="~/Agfdsgpx?node=find">Find</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Repdfsgs</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ssdfgrt</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Adgfdminisgfdon</a></li>
</ul>
```

Well, instead of using custom colors and such, I'd like to use `.ui-state-default` and `.ui-state-hover`

How would I use these classes without copy and pasting them into my own custom css class based on AVPNav?

Also, I'm looking for a pure css/html solution, but some light jquery use would be ok if it is the only way.

Comment: I don't think jQuery UI has default visual styling for drop down menus. Those classes might work, but they're really designed for other UI elements. If you want to use them, you'd want to extend the jQuery UI CSS to handle your particular markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can asssign class to DOM element only by hands or via javascript.

Comment: I ended up just using jquery to just add and remove the css classes when hovering

Answer (score 1):

CSS does not support this.

You must define the CSS yourself, or include the jquery CSS files in your application.

Comment: I do include the jquery CSS in my application, the problem is getting it to use the jquery classes

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as inheritance in CSS - even the `inherit` attribute value refers to DOM-level inheritance, not inheritance of CSS selectors.

Having said that, the ability to apply multiple classes to a single element is usually perfectly sufficient for most people:

```
<li id="someItem" class="someClass ui-state-default"> ...
```

If that won't work for you, then I'm afraid it's time for some <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: How would you get the :hover element with this though? I'm fine with putting in that markup, but you can't do `ui-state-hover` unless it globally affects every `li` can you?

Comment: @Earlz: Do it the same way jQuery UI does it - apply it with JavaScript using a hover/mouseover event.